# Filtering shapefile layer in ArcPad?

Tags: shapefile, filter, arcpad, vbscript

I have an ArcPad 10.2 project that uses several Shapefile layers.

How can I filter the features in one of those layers?

According to my searches, I can only filter if it is an AXF layer.

I'm happy to resort to scripting in vbs if required.

The layer I have has features that each have a status field, and it is this I wish to be able to quickly filter on.  I have to keep it as a shapefile really, as they are getting auto generated out of another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick,

I think you've answered you own question really, only AXF layers support filtering. If the source must stay as shapefile then there are only two alternatives that I can think of.

You create a form that allows you to choose your subset of features (e.g. species = oak) then this does one of 2 things:

- Create a new layer and builds a symbology for that layer where it deletes all but the required symbol. I've not checked in the the ArcPad object model supports that level of fine tweaking.
- Selects and copies the choose features to a new shapefile. This may not be viable if you have thousands of features to copy out every time?

It may be easier to use the AXF format and write an import/export routine to turn the results back into a shapefile when back in the office?